# Как задать вывод цикла в строку Python

Tags: python-3.x, for

```
a, b, c, d = int(input()), int(input()), int(input()), int(input())
for i in range(c, d + 1):
    print("\t", i, end="")
    print()
    for j in range(a, b + 1):
        print("\n", j, "\t", i * j, end='')
        print()
```

В основном цикле параметр `end=""` не помогает повлиять на вывод[image: желаемый результат на скриншоте].

Comment: Приводите конкретные тестовые примеры, пожалуйста. Что на входе, что ожидается на выходе, что на самом деле на выходе. Тогда выше шанс получить помощь.

Comment: Для чего служит `print()` на последней строке?

Comment: я так понимаю это таблица умножения ? зачем вы еще раз выводите множители, если они не меняются ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае следует использовать другой подход - формировать целиком нужные строки, не уверен что будет работать для всех ваших вариантов, но уже сможете сами поднастроить `rjust` позволяет выровнять числа по заданной ширине.

```
print (' '.join(str(x).rjust(9) for x in [c, d]))
for j in range(a, b + 1):
   print(' '.join(str(x).rjust(4) for x in [j, c * j, j, d * j]))
```

выведет:

```
        5         6
   7   35    7   42
   8   40    8   48
   9   45    9   54
  10   50   10   60
```